# How to set up width percentage basis?

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem:
I'd like to create a html page where a `#sidebar` spans a constant 27px and a `#content` spans the remaining part of the screen. The `#content` is divided into two areas splitting it at 40% - 60%.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="forty-percent">
      </div>
      <div id="sixty-percent">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to make the following css:

```
#sidebar{
  width:27px;
}
#content{
  position:absolute;
  padding-left:27px;
  width:100%;
}
```

But then I cannot divide the content into 40%-60%, because percentages are calculated from the width of the `#content` and not from its area inside.

What am I doing wrong? Can you please help?

UPDATE:

The demo of the NOT working version:

http://jsbin.com/iseqon/1/edit

Ideally the dashed boxes should be side-by-side, inside the blue box.

Comment: please put your html also OR make a jsfiddle.

Comment: I did both, now, I hope it helps.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yWjMC/

Comment: This guide my be of help in learning how to apply a solution - http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design

Comment: @limelights Exactly, I want to do something like that but it only works with height in px, but it does not work with height:100%. :(

Comment: `height` never works with percentages unless you set it 100% on the parent container. Look here http://jsfiddle.net/yWjMC/1/

Comment: Is it a typo or do you have really have '#' in your id tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may suit more your needs. If you want to have a better control of your #sidebar & #content vertical alignment, you must use inline-block to have a CSS only solution.

You can view it live here: http://codepen.io/jpsirois/pen/dvbmEy

```
* {
  /* This prevent padding to be added on defined width */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body {
  font-size: 0; /* Need to be set to 0 to properly use inline-block here */
  color: white; /* For a better preview purpose only */
}

#sidebar,
#content {
  display: inline-block; /* Allow vertical-align control (float didn’t) */
  font-size: 16px; /* Reset font-size to normal */
  vertical-align: middle; /* Demo of vertical-alignement */
}

#sidebar {
  width: 27px; 
  background: darkred;
  height: 50px; /* For a better preview purpose only */
  margin-right: -27px; /* This allow #content to be inlined aside */
}

#content {
  font-size: 0; /* Need to be set to 0 to properly use inline-block here */
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 27px;
}

#forty-percent,
#sixty-percent {
  height: 100px;/* For a better preview purpose only */
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px; /* Reset font-size to normal */
}

#forty-percent {
  width: 40%;
  background: darkgreen;
}

#sixty-percent {
  width: 60%;
  background: darkblue;
}
```

Comment: Cool! I was looking for this box-sizing stuff! Awesome, thx! I think this would work with height:100%, if I will use absolute positioning... right?

Comment: As I said, you have to define a height of the parent container otherwise you're gonna have a percentage of what? Defining a fixed height on the parent container is a must.

Comment: Box-Sizing is definitely a must these days. You just have to be aware if you have to support IE7, it’s only available since IE8.

If you use position absolute you will no more be able to use the vertical-align. It’s really depend of your needs. If you describe it, I may be able to help you find a proper solution.

Comment: @limelights : it is not. If you define eg. body{height:100%;} that means that the body spans the whole window area. Inside the body the percentages are theoretically relative to the nearest parent with non-static positioning.

Comment: @JPSirois: indeed, thx, I've found this box-sizing helps me solving many other problems I had difficulty with.

Answer (score 2):

You need this to float the `#sidebar` and give an equal `margin-left` to the `#content`, and also float the two inner boxes so they can sit side by side..

```
#sidebar {
    width:27px;
    float:left;
}
#content {
    margin-left:27px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#forty-percent {
    width:40%;
    float:left;
}
#sixty-percent {
    width:60%;
    float:left;
}
```

and also to not use the ***#*** char in the actual `id`

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8a7CN/

(*your fixed jsbin demo at http://jsbin.com/iseqon/4/edit you need to keep in mind that borders add to the width so it cannot work with percentages very well*)

Comment: I decided to keep accepting the version with box-sizing because it helped me more on the long run.

Answer (score 1):

how about having a parent div that would be relative and then having the div inside float right or left with absolute position within container. when the parent container is pos relative and the child is pos absolute, the children with position with respect to their container. In other words, something like that (untested but should give you the right idea)

```
#wrapper {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  margin:50px;
}
#leftCol {
  width:60%;
  background-color:yellow;

}
#rightCol {
  width:40%;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
</style>  


<div id='wrapper'>
  <div='leftCol'>
  </div>
  <div id='rightCol'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that the wrapper should not have a fixed width, but should span the remaining part of the body.

Comment: oh, how about margin-right on the content and position the sidebar absolute right relative to container?

Comment: Now the wrapper reaches well beyond the screen width. :(

Comment: that's due to the margin ... you could remove that or adjust wrapper size

Answer (score -2):

```
I am using your HTML only change the CSS.
My CSS is

#sidebar
{
width:27px;
min-width:27px;
float:left;
}

#content
{
float:right;
width:100%-28px;
min-width:100%-28px;
}

#forty-percent
{
width:40%;
float:left;
}
#sixty-percent
{
width:60%;
float:right;
}

Hope this will help you.Thanks.
```

Comment: you cannot perform calculations in CSS with the `calc()` method

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli I am not use calc() method.And parentage and fixed value manipulation is possible in CSS.See this link http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/outside.html. And before down vote study well..

Comment: did you actually read that article ? it is done with multiple elements and not with calculation inside CSS properties (*which cannot be done*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli It isn't fully supported, but yes you can http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc

Comment: @Llepwryd, i know, i mentioned that in my 1st comment.. but amit believes `calc` is not required.. (*and noticing my comment i see that i mistakenly wrote **with** instead of **without***)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Ah, fair enough. You're right then, you would need the calc() method. :)